# Is there an app to read QR code of smartcontract bytecode and trigger it?

Tags: android, bytecode

I want to know if there is a workaround for a smartphone user to simply scan a QR code that would trigger a transaction using a custom smartcontract (not a native currency). The contract would behave differently depending on who calls it.

This question tells me how to generate the QR : [Can any information beside the address be encoded into QR code?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5842/can-any-information-beside-the-address-be-encoded-into-qr-code/5843#5843)

What I don't is what app to read it with. Any idea ? The simpler, the better.

*FYI if it helps : The use case is waste management in a railway station. What I want is that when a bin is taken out, the guy scan the QR code and it generate an amount of a type waste. Then when the truck comes, the guy scan it too and the kg are transferred to this contractor accounts (with multiple contractors who picks up wastes). I need it to be the same QR code.

I have made small contracts and tokens that transfer kg of different kind of waste between accounts. I also have the contract that behaves correctly depending on who calls it (generate waste, transfer). We already have the guys on the field scanning codes… it sends me SMS and I input the transaction manually :D !*

Comment: Etienne, were you able to find out how to do this. I am looking for something similar.

Comment: No, not really. I've coded a meteor app that triggers the contract, but we moved away from QR at the same time (to beacons). A custom app with web3.js and QR library seems the only way right now.